# Automate clicking these control panel settings every time I boot?

Tags: windows, windows-10, automation, boot-camp, control-panel

I have a late 2012 MacBook Pro dual-booted into Windows 10 using MacOS Boot Camp. Every time I boot into Windows, I have to enable these Boot Camp Control Panel settings to enable trackpad 2-finger scroll, right-clicking ("Secondary Tap"), and "Tap to Click":

[image]

Since I use a Lightning-port Ethernet adapter which disconnects at least once a day (more often twice), I have to reboot my laptop quite frequently (since [Lightning-port devices in BootCamp cannot be recognized again after they've disconnected, unless you reboot](http://web.archive.org/web/20130421143056/http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US#12)).

So automating these settings would be fantastic for me. I'm actually quite stunned how little automated mouse movement software/Windows settings automation seems to be discussed by the general populace.

And yes, I've tried multiple times re-downloading & installing the latest BootCamp drivers for my hardware. (Side-note, the screen brightness keyboard controls no longer work after upgrading BootCamp from Win7->Win10 either)

I know it's a shot in the dark with little hope for a real solution, but I'm open to any advice. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried with Autohotkey?

Comment: @MikhailV - You were right -- It was possible. Thanks for the push in the right direction. It was an utter nightmare of inconsistencies, conflicts, and unexpected behavior to get there. But was nice to come to a solution in the end. I spent the last 13 hours automating not only this, but using AutoHotKey to fix the lacking brightness keyboard shortcut issue as well...Will post solution when I wake up at 7pm or whatever (It's 11AM now...I was too stubborn to go to bed until this was finished)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I scripted a solution for myself using AutoHotkey that ticks all the boxes in my original question automatically on login.

It also implements a script that re-enables the `F1`/`F2` brightness adjust keys.

I posted the AutoHotkey script and a setup binary on my GitHub in case it's useful to anyone else:

https://github.com/wad11656/Restore-Boot-Camp-Brightness-Keys

[Download](https://github.com/wad11656/Restore-Boot-Camp-Brightness-Keys/releases)